# How to make searching mechanism by name,surname,ssn entered from entering a single textbox?

Tags: .net, regex

I wrote a search mechanism.It works good.But I want to develop it to search more accurate.How to do it?

Suppose I wrote the name and surname and ssn or tc(in turkey),I am waiting only one record but my algorithm brings more records.How to improve it? My basic algorithm is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            Person p1 = new Person("John",              "Smith",    "28249690820");
            Person p2 = new Person("John Jack",         "Smith",    "28249690821");
            Person p3 = new Person("Ahmet",             "Willi",    "28249690827");
            Person p4 = new Person("John Brat",         "Willi",    "28249690829");
            Person p5 = new Person("Angelina",          "Smith",    "28249690831");
            Person p6 = new Person("Jack",              "Smith",    "28249690834");
            Person p7 = new Person("Jack Smith",        "",         "28249690837");
            Person p8 = new Person("John Jack Smith",   "",         "28249690835");
            Person p9 = new Person("John Brat",         "Williams", "28249690839");

            List<Person> l = new List<Person>();

            l.Add(p1);
            l.Add(p2);
            l.Add(p3);
            l.Add(p4);
            l.Add(p5);

            string[] filterArray = GetFilterGroup("John Smith 28249690820").ToArray();//just one record must come 

            string filterString = "";

            if (filterArray.Length == 0)
            {
                filterString = ".";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var obj in filterArray)
                {
                    filterString += obj + "|";
                }
                filterString = filterString.Substring(0, filterString.Length - 1);
            }

            Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"("+filterString+")");

            var queryMatchingFiles = (from a in l
                 where (searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Name) || searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Surname)||searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Tc))
                 select new
                 {
                     a
                 }).ToList();


            foreach (var x in queryMatchingFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : "+x.a.Name+"\t\t"+"Surname : "+x.a.Surname);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFilterGroup(string str)
    {
        var items = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var groups = new List<string>(items);


        for (int i = 1; i < items.Count(); i++)
        {
            groups.Add(string.Join(" ", items.Where((s, idx) => idx <= i)));
        }

        return groups;
    }
}

 class Person
 {
     private string name;
     private string surname;
     private string tc;

     public Person(string name, string surname, string tc)
     {
         this.name = name;
         this.surname = surname;
         this.tc = tc;
     }

     public string Name
     {
         get { return name; }
         set { name = value; }
     }

     public string Surname
     {
         get { return surname; }
         set { surname = value; }
     }

     public string Tc
     {
         get { return tc; }
         set { tc = value; }
     }
 }
```

}

[[image]
[image]

Comment: Try replacing the regex declaration with `Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"^("+filterString+")$");` I think all you need is to retrict the search to *whole string match*.

Comment: @stribizhev the result is not what I want unfortunately. I am waiting just person 1(p1) because all fields of p1 object mathes the search terms.See the attachment.

Comment: Aha, I thought you just wanted to check if *any* of them match. So, revert the regex declaration to what it was before (`Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"("+filterString+")");`), and replace `where` clause to `where (searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Name) && searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Surname) && searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Tc))`

Comment: thanks it is good but when I wrote the John or Smith or Joh or John Smith any record does not  come. I am waiting to come more specific record by giving detail info about person.

Comment: What is the exact input do you provide?

Comment: I can say that the user can enter Joh or John or John Smith or Joh Smith or John Smith or Smith or 28249690820 etc.I want to multidirectional search.

Comment: Check [this page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-search)

Comment: this is exactly what you want